# Inherited controller method without type parameter does not get mapped with RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I created a base Spring controller for my latest web app project that I inherit from for all my basic CRUD controllers, called CrudController:

```
class CrudController<T, K extends Serializable>
```

T is the Entity type, and K is the key used for that type (pretty much the parameters needed for Spring's CrudRepository). I create a rest controller by extending it, like so:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/hats")
public class HatController extends CrudController<Hat, Integer> {
}
```

Everything works great, except for the method that gets the list of items, `/hats`. With this method, I get a 405 Method Not Allowed. When I look at the logging that was done during startup, I can see that RequestMappingHandlerMapping did not map `{[/hats],methods=[GET]}` but it did map the other four methods in the controller. Here is the code for the method that isn't being mapped:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<?> getAll() {
    Iterable<T> result = controllerRepository.findAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

After much experimentation, I have discovered that if I add a parameter to the getAll method that is one of the class parameter types, the method will get mapped. Check this very similar code out:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<?> getAll(K dontuse) {
    Iterable<T> result = controllerRepository.findAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

With that small code change, the `/find` call works fine. I can keep my dummy parameter in there and everything will work, but it smells.

Any ideas? A simplified project that replicates the issue can be found here:

[Simple Project](https://github.com/qanwi1970/RequestMapping_Issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently a bug in Java, see bug reports [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8142904) and [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6815786), where [`Class#getDeclaredMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--) returns a bridge `Method` for each inherited method from a superclass declared as package-private. Based on the javadoc, it shouldn't do that.

This confuses Spring MVC's inspection of `@Controller` annotated classes and handler methods. Going into detail in this answer won't be very useful, but you can look at the code that handles it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.2.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java#L224).

The simplest solution is to declare your `CrudRepository` class as `public`.

```
public class CrudController<T, K extends Serializable>
```

Comment: this is fantastic troubleshooting, +1